# How to extract max records after aggregation in reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My input data is in below format

```
Roll Number | School Name | Name | Age | Gender | Class | Subject | Marks
04|DPS|Hasini|15|F|tenth|English|80
04|DPS|Hasini|15|F|tenth|Maths|2
04|DPS|Hasini|15|F|tenth|Science|49
04|DPS|Hasini|15|F|tenth|Social|94
04|DPS|Hasini|15|F|tenth|Hindi|6
01|DAV|Praveen|12|M|seventh|Telugu|52
01|DAV|Praveen|12|M|seventh|English|69
01|DAV|Praveen|12|M|seventh|Maths|65
01|DAV|Praveen|12|M|seventh|Science|37
```

I need to find students with highest marks in class

output :

```
Name | Class | Marks ( only those with highest marks)
```

I wrote a reducer which aggregates on Name and Class and sums the Marks,so I have a list of Name | Class | Total Marks , I am trying to figure out how to extract students with highest marks any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Define "students with highest marks" please. Do you want a descending sorting, based on marks? Do you want the student(s) with the highest mark? Do you want the students with the highest *k* marks? Do you want the student with the highest mark per class?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need students with highest marks per class.